# SSH Proxy Session Hung Indefinitely

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, dropbear

I have an SSH connection flow of `client -> proxy server -> server` which is established via Net::SSH::Proxy in ruby (this looks to be an SSH problem, not a ruby problem). Once the connection is established, subsequent commands are sent over the tunnel until the connection is closed. This works fine ~99% of the time, however, occasionally the tunnel will get held open indefinitely and seems to correlate with a reboot of the server while there is an active connection. If I try to reproduce that scenario manually (reboot the server while there is an active connection) I am not able to do so, instead the ssh connection closes as expected.

When the tunnel is stuck in this indefinite open state, the connection from `client -> proxy server` is still established and the `proxy server` thinks the connection to the `server` is also still established. However, the `server` **does not** show an established connection from the `proxy server` which makes sense because it has rebooted.

Data collected from each of the hosts:

**Client (uses OpenSSH):**

```
ps -o cmd= -p 8029
ssh -o strictHostKeyChecking=no user1@172.29.3.64 -p 2022 -W [10.100.202.65]:22

TZ=UTC0 ps -o lstart= -p 8029
Mon Jul  8 21:17:09 2019
```

**Proxy Server (uses OpenSSH):**

```
sudo netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd' | grep 10.100.202.65
tcp        0      0 10.100.201.246:47414    10.100.202.65:22        ESTABLISHED 29135/sshd: user1
```

**Server (uses Dropbear)**

```
netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*dropbear' | grep 10.100.202.65
<...no results...>

date; uptime
Tue Jul  9 18:56:49 UTC 2019
18:56:49 up 21:37,  load average: 0.50, 0.56, 0.61
```

^ notice that the server `date - uptime` = `Mon Jul 8 21:19 UTC` whereas the client command has been running since `Mon Jul 8 21:17 UTC` confirming that the server rebooted after the connection had been established.

My first thought was that maybe the proxy server's sshd had `TCPKeepAlive` disabled and therefore it was not able to detect the server connection going down, but I confirmed in sshd_config that it is enabled:
`TCPKeepAlive yes`

I also took a tcpdump on the proxy server but the only traffic seen for the destination server are occasional ARPs:

```
sudo tcpdump -ni eth1 host 10.100.202.65
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
11:14:45.647479 ARP, Request who-has 10.100.0.2 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 10.100.202.65, length 46
11:14:45.660208 ARP, Request who-has 10.100.202.65 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 0.0.0.0, length 46
11:15:46.762554 ARP, Request who-has 10.100.0.2 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 10.100.202.65, length 46
11:15:46.782608 ARP, Request who-has 10.100.202.65 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 0.0.0.0, length 46
11:16:47.956901 ARP, Request who-has 10.100.0.2 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 10.100.202.65, length 46
11:16:47.974012 ARP, Request who-has 10.100.202.65 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 0.0.0.0, length 46
```

**Question:** What could be keeping the ssh connection established? Are there any additional ssh options (either in sshd config or command line arg) that can be used to prevent this?

**EDIT:** I believe I found the issue. The client's `ssh_config` contains ServerAlive* options of:

```
    ServerAliveCountMax 3
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

which will kill an idle session after 3 min. The `proxy server` in this path is also acting as a client with its connection to the `server`. The `proxy server` did not have these options set. I have now added them to `ssh_config` on the `proxy server` and I will make another edit to report whether this was successful or not.